# Knockout: valueAccessor vs viewModel on custom binding handlers?

Tags: knockout.js

What's the difference between getting access to a view model's values through the binding properties (via valueAccessor) and getting them from the viewModel argument passed to the handler's init and update? I have always assumed the answer is that those model properties linked to valueAccessor automatically set up bindings (which would fire an update on any change to observables) but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `valueAccessor` argument gives you access to specifically what was passed into the binding, while the `viewModel` argument gives you access to the entire data object at the scope.

So, if someone says `text: firstName`

`valueAccessor()` would give you the `firstName` observable/property and `viewModel` would give you access to the object that contains `firstName`.

Comment: I might not have been clear in my original post but I'm not confused about the difference between the two. What I'm confused about is why you wouldn't always just use `viewModel`, since it contains everything `valueAccessor()` does and more. My initial guess, which is something I've not tested or been able to confirm clearly in the docs, is that what you pass into `valueAccessor()` automatically sets up a binding, which would create a clear need. Maybe it's not true in all cases that one would be the superset of the other? Can you give a case where valueAccessor() is the only viable option?

Comment: `valueAccessor` does not do anything special. Any observable that has its value accessed will create a dependency. The use case is really that say you have `firstName` and `lastName` observables on your view model. In a binding you would do `text: firstName`. In your binding handler, you would use `valueAccessor` to understand what specific observable/property that you want to act on (`firstName` as opposed to `lastName` or any other property).  So, while the `viewModel` arg contains all of the data, you still need to know what was passed to the binding specifically.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. It's basically the equivalent to having explicit arguments on a method that also accepts a context argument.