# Knockout Js custom binding handler update dependency

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This post:
[Knockout: valueAccessor vs viewModel on custom binding handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476898/knockout-valueaccessor-vs-viewmodel-on-custom-binding-handlers) makes the following statement about how the viewModel observables are bound within a custom binding handler:
*"Any observable that has its value accessed will create a dependency."*

How do I access a value from the observable X on the viewModel inside a custom binding handler ***without*** creating a dependency that makes the custom binding handler to update if X is later changed?

I made a Fiddle that showcases this. The line `viewModel.xxx();` creates a dependency to the "xxx" observable.

http://jsfiddle.net/hhw4a/5/

Comment: If you are using KO 2.3+, then you can do `viewModel.xxx.peek()` as well

Comment: That's an even better solution that works without need of extra code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Best workaround you have available, afaik: create a plain vanilla JavaScript property, and reference *that*.  Something like this:

```
function Vm(){
    this.aOb = ko.observable('a value');
    this.a = this.aOb();
}
```

Now you may reference `a` in your custom bindings, and changes to aOb will not cause your binding to re-fire.

And if you want to always keep a in sync with aOb, you can use subscribe:

```
function Vm(){
    this.aOb = ko.observable('a value');
    this.a = this.aOb();

    this.aOb.subscribe(function(newVal){
       this.a = newVal;
    }.bind(this));
}
```